# Defining a map to arrays containing slices in Golang

Tags: arrays, go, slice

In Go (golang), is it possible to define a map from strings to arrays, and in each array element I want to store a slice. Like this:

```
var data = make(map[string][2]Slice[]float64)
```

Then I want to retrieve my data, something like this:

```
floatValue0 = data["string-key"][0][#]
floatValue1 = data["string-key"][1][#]
```

Comment: It should be `var data = make(map[string][2][]float64)`. But yes, it will work.

Comment: To add to @AndySchweig's comment, here's an example: https://play.golang.org/p/3HZgsnH2Xi

Comment: map values are arbitrary types.   Literally any type at all.  Map keys have some restrictions - anything /comparable/ will do, as defined here:  https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I'm sorry to see that the question itself was not appreciated. Unfortunately stackoverflow may penalize me for removing the question. For the future it would be beneficial for me to know why this question was not appreciated. Eli5.

Answer (score 0):

data := map[string][2][]float64{"golang": {[]float64{3.14, 3.15}, []float64{3.12, 3.16}}}

fmt.Println(data["golang"][0][0])

output:
3.14